# Meaning of "barrer" (noun) in W. Henley's poem "'Liza"

Tags: meaning, slang, poetry, literature

I don't understand the meaning in which the count noun word "barrer" is used in William Henley's poem ['Liza](https://archive.org/stream/lavenderhawthorn00henlrich#page/78/mode/1up) (the italics are the author's):

> *’Liza’s old man’s* perhaps a little *shady*,
>   *’Liza’s old woman’s* prone to *booze* and cringe;
>   But *’Liza* deems herself *a perfect lady*,
>   And proves it in her feathers and her fringe.
>   For *’Liza* has a *bloke* her heart to cheer,
>   With *pearlies* and a ***barrer*** and a *jack*,
>   So all the vegetables of the year
>   Are duly represented on her back.
>   Her boots are sacrifices to her hats,
>   Which knock you speechless—*like a load of bricks!*
>   Her summer velvets dazzle *Wanstead Flats*,
>   And cost, at times, a good eighteen-and-six.
>      Withal, outside the gay and giddy whirl,
>      *’Liza’s* a stupid, straight, hard-working girl.

I understand *pearlies* to mean either pearly-white teeth or mother-of-pearl buttons. *A jack* is probably some mechanical part the *bloke* uses to bruise 'Liza's back with ("all the vegetables of the year").

But **barrer** is a mystery. Could it be the Cockney pronunciation of "barrow"?

Comment: Almost certainly the East-London was of saying Barrow as you surmised.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it is. A 'barrer-boy' is a hawker of fruit and vegetables from a barrow in the street.

Comment: I thought maybe _pearlies_ might be pearl onions, but Google Ngram suggests that this name was not used during Henley's lifetime.

Comment: It'd be pronounced ba-ra. Common English speakers often do that with words that end with *ow*, pronouncing *window* as *windah* and so on.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! @Barmar, I've found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearly_Kings_and_Queens) page that probably bears relation to the *pearlies* of the poem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, fifth edition (1961), may be citing this very passage in his entry for *pearlies*:

> **pearlies.** (The singular hardly exists.) Pearl buttons, esp. on a coster's clothes : from ca. 1885 : low coll. Henley.

A *coster* or *costermonger*, Partridge says, is "orig. *costard-monger*, at first a seller of apples, then of any fruit, finally of fruit, fish, vegetables, etc.., from a barrow," which clarifies the "barrer" part of the line.

Unfortunately, *jack* has so many slang meanings—including, Partridge says, "A single carnation (sold as a choice carnation) : horticultural s[lang] (—1878)" and "A variety of tea-rose : coll. : abbr. *Jacqueminot* : 1883"—that I have no idea which one Henley intended here. The carnation would go with the mother-of-pearl buttons, you might think, but there are numerous other possibilities.

As for "all the vegetables of the year" being represented on Liza's back, perhaps she wears the seasonal leftovers from the barrow on her hats each day, thereby justifying the simile "like a load of bricks."